# Python arithmetic quiz task 1

Tags: python

I have no idea why this code is not working, as you can see I'm trying to ask the user 10 questions display their score at the end. Everything works except that the score will always appear as a `0` or `1` at the end, even if more than `1` question was answered right.
Here is my code:

```
import random
studentname=input("what is your name?:")
def question():
    global operation
    global number1
    global number2
    global studentanswer
    global score
    operation=random.choice(["*","-","+"])
    score=0
    trueanswer=0
    number1=random.randrange(1,10)
    number2=random.randrange(1,10)
    print("what is", number1,operation,number2,"?:")
    studentanswer=int(input("insert answer:"))

def checking():
    global score
    if operation == "*":
        trueanswer = number1*number2
        if studentanswer == trueanswer:
            print("correct")
            score=score+1
        else:
            print("incorrect")
            score=score
    elif operation == "-":
        trueanswer = number1-number2
        if studentanswer == trueanswer:
            print("correct")
            score=score+1
        else:
            print("incorrect")
            score=score
    elif operation == "+":
        trueanswer = number1+number2
        if studentanswer == trueanswer:
            print("correct")
            score = score+1
        else:
           print("incorrect")
           score=score

def main():
    for i in range (10):
        question()
        checking()
    print("your score is", score)

main()
```

Comment: Choose a meaningful phrase for title. `Python arithmetic quiz task 1` is very poor title as it doesn't give any idea of your problem.

Comment: Your code is very poorly structured. Your functions are unreusable, because they read input from globals and assign result  to them. You see, unless function is designed to deal with "the outer world" (like `main`), it should take input as parameters, and `return` it's result.

Answer (score 2):

Each call to `question()` resets `score` to be `0`. Remove the `score=0` line from that function, and instead initialize it in `main`:

```
def main():
    global score;
    score = 0;
    for i in range (10):
        question()
        checking()
    print("your score is", score)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can error check to see if your variable to count has been initialized. It's not the cleanest solution but does the job.

```
def checking():
try:
    global score
    score = score
except:
    global score
    score = 0

if operation == "*":
    trueanswer = number1*number2
    if studentanswer == trueanswer:
        print("correct")
        score=score+1
```